# factorial - recursion in C and Assembler

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, x86

I've written algorithm which is counting factorial in assembler. I am beginner in assembler and I would like to have a piece of advice from you if this algorithm is good.

```
unsigned long int k = 12;
unsigned long int result = 1;
unsigned long factorial = k;

unsigned long int C_recursion(unsigned int k){

if (k < 2)
    return 1;
return k*C_recursion(k - 1);}


int ASM_recursion(unsigned long int k, unsigned long int result){

__asm {

    xor eax, eax        
    xor ebx, ebx        
    mov eax, k          
    mov ebx, factorial
    if :
    cmp factorial, 2
    jge recursion       
    jmp end
    recursion :
    dec factorial           
    mul factorial       
        jmp if
        end :
    mov result, eax 
}
return result;}
```

Well, everything works but honestly i don't know if this assembler code is really recursion. I am writing it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Your assembly code is not recursive.

Comment: Recursion usually involves functions calling themselves. In x86 assembly this means pushing things onto the stack while looping over blocks of code, though this code is not always that different from other non-recursive code depending on the problem being solved since you're working at such a low level. Many compilers will actually use [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to flatten recursive calls into simple loops.

Comment: I didnt have any problems with iterativ algorithm, but i dont have any idea how to make recursion. I have to hand out the code till tommorow :/

Comment: @nickma Make `factorial` call itself to compute the value according to the formula `factorial(n) = factorial(n - 1) * n`.

Comment: It may have been written recursively, but good compilers can recognize "tail" recursion and re-code it as iteration, which seems to have been done here.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion function must call itself. I see you writing under 32bits, you can try this

```
int factorial (int n)
{
__asm {
    cmp n,0
    je return1 // n == 0, return 1
    mov ecx,n
    sub ecx,1
    push ecx  // ecx == n-1
    call factorial
    add esp,4  // pop (n) argument from stack
    imul eax,n  // n * factorial(n-1)
    jmp return2
    return1:
     mov eax,1
    return2:
}
}
```

Line `jmp return2` is very important, you cannot insert `ret` instruction there, because compiler may add a few instructions to build frame stack (`ebp` register may be used, it depends on optimization flags used).

Comment: Thank you, its working. But to be honest i dont understand one thing. There is operation "CALL", it pushes adress of next instruction to the stack and this all function restarts ? Well, i have no idea when operation imul eax,n is done :x

Comment: We must remember that in this code there is a `ret` instruction (it was added by compiler at the end of factorial function).  `ret` instruction pop from the stack address of next instruction to be done. While leaving _factorial_ procedure `ret` instruction is executed, and then `eax` is multiplied by `n` - which was pushed onto the stack.

Comment: I have one more question, instruction push ecx pushes ecx on stack and then subtract 1 from k? Like in first call of function ecx = 4 and k = 5. ecx is pushed onto a stack and k is decremented by 1?

Comment: i mean n, not k